# How can I change between two tables in SQL database when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a dictionary app getting data from SQL database.
This database has a "First table" table with 3 columns id, word, meaning ( word in french meaning in English)

I've insert a new table "Second table" with the same columns but this time is the opposite I mean (word in English meaning in french)
I want to insert a button to switch between search method "search using french Word and button to search using English word"
when user clicked the button "FR > ENG" I want to get the data from the first table (word in french meaning in English) and do the opposite when click 
button "ENG > FR" using the second table that I've added before (word in English meaning in french)

DataBaseHelper.java

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static String DB_PATH;
    public final Context context;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public static String DB_NAME = "Database";
    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return this.database;
    }


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

        this.context = context;
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", new Object[]{context.getPackageName()});
        openDataBase();
    }
    public void createDataBase() {
        if (checkDataBase()) {
            Log.i(getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
            return;
        }
        getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 0);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        if (checkDb != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream externalDbStream = this.context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } else {
                localDbStream.close();
                externalDbStream.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (this.database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, 0);
        }
        return this.database;
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if (this.database != null) {
            this.database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

DataManager.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataManager {
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataManager(Context context) {
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
        db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    //Get All Data
    public List<Word> getAllData() {
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from table_fr_eng LIMIT 5000;", null);
        List<Word> item_data = new ArrayList<Word>();
        if (cur.getCount() != 1) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Word obj = new Word();
                    obj.id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Id"));
                    obj.word = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Word"));
                    obj.is_fav = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("is_favourite"));
                    if (obj.is_fav!=null) {
                    } else {
                        obj.is_fav="0";
                    }
                    obj.meaning = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Meaning"));
                    item_data.add(obj);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return item_data;
    }

    //Get Search Data
    public List<Word> getAllSearchData(String search) {
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_fr_eng WHERE Word LIKE '" + search + "%' LIMIT 30", null);
        List<Word> item_data = new ArrayList<Word>();
        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Word obj = new Word();
                    obj.id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Id"));
                    obj.word = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Word"));
                    obj.is_fav = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("is_favourite"));
                    if (obj.is_fav!=null) {
                    } else {
                        obj.is_fav="0";
                    }
                    obj.meaning = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Meaning"));
                    item_data.add(obj);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return item_data;
    }

    //Add Word And Meaning 
    public Boolean InsertWord(String strWord, String strMeaning) {
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO table_fr_eng(Word,Meaning) values('" + strWord + "','"
                + strMeaning + "')";
        db.execSQL(insertQuery);
        db.close();
        return true;
    }

    //Get Day of The Word
    public Word DayOfWord() {
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_fr_eng ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ;",null);
        Word objWord = new Word();
        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    objWord.word = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Word"));
                    objWord.meaning = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Meaning"));
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return objWord;
    }

    //Add Favourite Word
    public void FavouriteWord(String id) {
        String updateQuery = "UPDATE table_fr_eng SET is_favourite='"+1+"' WHERE Id=" +id;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(updateQuery);
        db.close();
    }
    //Add UnFavourite Word
    public void UnFavouriteWord(String id) {
        String updateQuery = "UPDATE table_fr_eng SET is_favourite='' WHERE Id=" +id;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(updateQuery);
        db.close();
    }
    //Get All Favourite Word
    public List<Word> getAllFavouriteData() {
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from table_fr_eng where is_favourite=1;",null);
        List<Word> item_data = new ArrayList<Word>();
        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Word obj = new Word();
                    obj.id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Id"));
                    obj.word = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Word"));
                    if (obj.is_fav!=null) {
                    } else {
                        obj.is_fav="1";
                    }
                    obj.meaning = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Meaning"));
                    item_data.add(obj);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return item_data;
    }
    //Add History 
    public void InsertHistoryWord(String word, String meaning) {
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tblHistory(word,meaning) values('" + word + "','"
                + Base64.encodeToString(meaning.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT) + "')";
        db.execSQL(insertQuery);
        db.close();
    }

    //Get All History Word
    public List<Word> getAllHistoryData() {
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from tblHistory;", null);
        List<Word> item_data = new ArrayList<Word>();
        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Word obj = new Word();
                    obj.id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Id"));
                    obj.word = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("word"));
                    obj.meaning = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("meaning"));
                    byte[] data1 = Base64.decode(obj.meaning, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    try {
                        obj.meaning = new String(data1, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    item_data.add(obj);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return item_data;
    }

    //Delete History 
    public List<Word> getDeleteHistoryData() {
        List<Word> item_data = new ArrayList<Word>();
        String deleteQuery = "delete from tblHistory";
        db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
        db.close();
        return item_data;
    }

    //Get Quiz Word and Meaning
    public List<Word> Quiz() {
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_fr_eng ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4 ;",null);
        List<Word> item_data = new ArrayList<Word>();
        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Word obj = new Word();
                    obj.id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Id"));
                    obj.word = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Word"));
                    obj.meaning = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Meaning"));
                    item_data.add(obj);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return item_data;
    }

    //Delete Favourite Word
    public List<Word> getDeleteFavouriteData() {
        List<Word> item_data = new ArrayList<Word>();
        String deleteQuery = "delete from table_fr_eng where is_favourite";
        db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
        db.close();
        return item_data;
    }

}
```

Comment: You would probably need to better document your question. What do you have? What do you want? Format your text so it is easier to read... No need to apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a working example that will give the meaning of the word entered into an edit text according to button clicked.

E.g. if **Yes** is entered and the **Eng->Fr** button is clicked it will say the ***Word Yes means Oui in French.***. If the **Fr->Eng** button is clicked it will say the ***Word Yes means I don't know in English.*** (i.e. there is no meaning of yes in French).

Conversly entering **Oui** will say ***Word Oui means Yes in English*** or ***Oui means I don't know in French.***

### MyDatabaseHelper.java

This is the subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper which is a typical way of accessing an SQLiteDatabase in Android :-

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "translator";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_ENGFR = "engfr";
    public static final String TBL_FRENG = "freng";

    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_WORD = "word";
    public static final String COl_MEANING = "meaning";

    public static final int TRANSLATOR_TYPE_ENGLISH_TO_FRENCH = 0;
    public static final int TRANSLATOR_TYPE_FRENCH_TO_ENGLISH = 1;


    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crt_table_sql(getTableToUse(TRANSLATOR_TYPE_ENGLISH_TO_FRENCH)));
        db.execSQL(crt_table_sql(getTableToUse(TRANSLATOR_TYPE_FRENCH_TO_ENGLISH)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public String getMeaningOfWord(String word, int type) {
        String rv = "";
        String whereclause = COL_WORD + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{word};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(getTableToUse(type),null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_MEANING));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public long addWord(String word, String meaning,int type) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_WORD,word);
        cv.put(COl_MEANING,meaning);
        return mDB.insert(getTableToUse(type),null,cv);
    }

    private String crt_table_sql(String table) {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                COl_MEANING + " TEXT" +
                ")";
    }

    private String getTableToUse(int type) {
        String rv = "";
        switch (type) {
            case    TRANSLATOR_TYPE_ENGLISH_TO_FRENCH:
                rv = TBL_ENGFR;
                break;
            case TRANSLATOR_TYPE_FRENCH_TO_ENGLISH:
                rv = TBL_FRENG;
                break;
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

In all instances the underlying table is determined according to an int value (0 (English to French) or 1 (French to English)) as represented by the two constants defined the the helper.

The constants are also used by the Buttons in the main activity to determine language of the meaning.

## MainActivity.java

This activity has 3 UI elements, an edit text for entering the word and the two buttons. Clicking one will use the respective table in order to ascertain the meaning of the word.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mWordToGetMeaningOf;
    Button mENG_TO_FR, mFR_TO_ENG;
    Context mContext;
    String mCurrentmeaning;
    MyDBHelper mDBhlpr;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        mWordToGetMeaningOf = this.findViewById(R.id.word_to_get_meaning_of);
        mENG_TO_FR = this.findViewById(R.id.eng_to_fr);
        mFR_TO_ENG = this.findViewById(R.id.fr_to_eng);
        mDBhlpr = new MyDBHelper(this);
        addSomeData();

        mENG_TO_FR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentmeaning = mDBhlpr.getMeaningOfWord(mWordToGetMeaningOf.getText().toString(),MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_ENGLISH_TO_FRENCH);
                displayMeaning(MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_ENGLISH_TO_FRENCH);
            }
        });
        mFR_TO_ENG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentmeaning = mDBhlpr.getMeaningOfWord(mWordToGetMeaningOf.getText().toString(),MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_FRENCH_TO_ENGLISH);
                displayMeaning(MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_FRENCH_TO_ENGLISH);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Toasts the meaning of the word (also writes the same message to the log)
     * @param type
     */
    private void displayMeaning(int type) {
        String meaning_type = "";
        switch (type) {
            case MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_ENGLISH_TO_FRENCH:
                meaning_type = "French";
                break;
            case MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_FRENCH_TO_ENGLISH:
                meaning_type = "English";
                break;
        }
        if (mCurrentmeaning.length() < 1) {
            mCurrentmeaning = " I don't know ";
        }
        String message = "The Word " +
                mWordToGetMeaningOf.getText().toString() +
                " means " + mCurrentmeaning +
                " in " + meaning_type + ".";
        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("MEANING",message);
    }

    /**
     * Add some testing data
     */
    private void addSomeData() {
        mDBhlpr.addWord("Yes","Oui",MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_ENGLISH_TO_FRENCH);
        mDBhlpr.addWord("Oui","Yes",MyDBHelper.TRANSLATOR_TYPE_FRENCH_TO_ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks You MikeT for your help i'm really grateful